# Today extension work properly on ios 8 but in ios 7 and above

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

I have added today widget in my app. it shows today notification in app on ios 8 properly.

but when i tried to run my app on ios 7. its not showing notification in today.

as per my research on google my device is not jailbroken.
both the target (app target and extension target) set 7.1.

also when i tried to run extension on ios 8 it run properly.
whenever i tried it on ios 7. cancel run without any error.

I have checked other demo app also. all app work on ios 8 but not on ios 7.
same result for that app also.

appreciate for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today extensions are a feature new in iOS 8. They are not supported in iOS 7.

https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

> App extensions give users access to your app’s functionality and content throughout iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite